# How to get certain files in Intellij IDEA just by name and not direct path

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, text, src

So let say I have a package called food in src folder inside my restaurant project. Then I created a file call recipe which contains some food names that is also inside the same food package. Then when I call to the file's name which is "recipe.txt", I get the error that can't find the file. So I have create a project call restaurant and inside it I have created a package called food and inside the package food, I have created a file called recipe.txt and tried to open it and read it by it does not let me.

I have tried all the different way I could, so first I tried to open and read it by direct path of the file which works->
String directPath = "C:\Users\Kevin\IdeaProjects\Restaurant\src\Food\Recipe.txt";
try {
Files.lines(Paths.get(directPath))
.forEach(System.out::println);
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("Error file: " + e.getMessage());
}
However, whenever I want to make it work where I can just use the name of the file because I have other problems where I open it from another class and direct path don't seem to work. So back to the original question where I want to use file name to open and read the file.
//String directPath = "C:\Users\Kevin\IdeaProjects\Restaurant\src\Food\Recipe.txt";
try {
Files.lines(Paths.get("recipe.txt"))
.forEach(System.out::println);
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("Error file: " + e.getMessage());
}
So I have confirmed that the file is in the correct directory since it is in the package called food and the Main class where I try to open and read the file is also in the package called food. I have also checked if I can access of edit a file by using the "file.exists","file.canRead","file.canWrite",and "file.canExecute". So I am quite sure that my file is not locked based on these tests? None other program is also using the file since I just created it to test. So I have no idea why I can not open the File just by using the File name since the file is accessible and is in the correct package. Thank you guys so much since this problem has been eating at me for so long.

Comment: (1) move `Recipe.txt` into `C:\Users\Kevin\IdeaProjects\Restaurant` directory (2) this is only for IDEA test.

Comment: They are already in the same directory; not sure what you mean by step 2 though.